# Como criar uma URL amigável em uma one-page

Tags: html

Tenho uma site que é one-page. Separei as telas por `<div>` para facilitar.
Porém, se eu clicar em **notícias** ele vai corretamente para a tela de notícias, mas a URL não muda.

Como faço para incluir uma URL amigável para cada "seção" dos site? De forma que o Google Analytics capture corretamente a URL que o usuário estiver.

Por exemplo, se eu clicar em **contato**, ele desse até a seção de contato e a URL fica www.meusite.com.br/contato

Abaixo, um pouco da minha estrutura principal para o site:

```
<div class="fundo1">CONTEUDO</div>
<div class="fundo2">CONTEUDO</div>
<div class="fundo3">CONTEUDO</div>
<div class="fundo4">CONTEUDO</div>
<div class="fundo5">CONTEUDO</div>
```

Comment: O site inteiro está contido nessa página? Não tem nada [carregado via Ajax](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/18747/15703) nem nada desse tipo?

Comment: A pergunta é boa. Se não se importa, coloque os trechos de código relevantes para entendermos como você está tentando fazer isso. Você já sabe como funciona [location hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) e [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)?

Comment: @Andrey Ótima sugestão essa do History API, não conhecia! Talvez com isso e mais [o uso do `analytics.js`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/screens?hl=pt-br) exista alguma solução viável. (e pensar que 10 minutos atrás eu estava *seguro* de que o que o AP queria era impossível... :P)

Comment: @mgibsonbr O History API é novo no HTML5 e não funciona em todos os browsers, mas grandes empresas como Google, Facebook e Twitter o utilizam. Relacionado com a pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26078/7261

Comment: @mgibsonbr existe uma parte do site que possui carregamento via Ajax. Andrey vou atualizar a pergunta incluindo alguns trechos do código.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Desconsidere meu primeiro comentário. Por um instante achei que sua pergunta era sobre SEO (e se fosse, seria um tantinho mais complicado), mas se o caso é "informar o Analytics de que o usuário acessou tal conteúdo" então é bem mais tranquilo... Eu não tenho experiência em primeira mão pra dar uma resposta agora (nem estou com tempo no momento), mas mais tarde se não tiver surgido uma solução eu volto a essa pergunta.

Comment: Tudo bem. De qualquer forma, editei a pergunta e coloquei um exemplo de como está a minha estrutura.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Usar hash (`#`) é uma solução possível.

Alterar o hash não faz o navegador disparar uma nova requisição.

Você pode alterar o hash de duas maneiras:

1. Via links:

```html
<a href="#noticias">Notícias</a>
```

2. Via Javascript:

```js
window.location.hash = "noticias";
```

É possível disparar um evento toda vez que o hash é mudado:

```js
// usando jQuery
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    alert(window.location.hash);
});
```

Caso o usuário acesse diretamente uma URL com hash como:

```
https://www.seu-site.com/#noticias
```

O ideal é criar um evento que carrega o conteúdo solicitado:

```js
// novamente com jQuery
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    var pagina = windows.location.hash;
    if (pagina === "#noticias") {
        // carrega "Notícias"
    }
}
```

Para ficar mais DRY, você pode criar uma função que carrega a página correta e dispará-la nos dois eventos (domready e hashchange):

```js
var carregaPagina = function() {
    var pagina = windows.location.hash;
    if (pagina === "#noticias") {
        // carrega "Notícias"
    }
};

$(document).on("ready", carregaPagina);
$(window).on("hashchange", carregaPagina);
```

Montei um [exemplo básico no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f49b4wz9/).

---

## Sobre o Google Analytics

Minha experiência com o Google Analytics é **zero**. Mas [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18652735/3153542) do Stack-EN sugere informar manualmente a requisição da página no evento `hashchange`. Eu não testei isso, mas acredito que [esta página](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages?hl=pt-br) informa exatamente como fazer isso.

---

## Existe ainda o History API

Não vou falar muito sobre ele, pois nunca o utilizei na prática. (Seria bom alguém com experiência dar uma resposta sobre ele).

Basicamente ele fornece um meio de artificialmente manipular o histórico do navegador, em conjunto com a URL, via Javascript, sem a necessidade do uso do hash. Isso é uma funcionalidade nova do HTML5, e não irá funcionar em navegadores antigos:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Links úteis

- [Documentação do History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)
- Pergunta relacionada no Stack-PT: [Client router vs server router?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26078/7261)
- [Sammy.js, biblioteca para roteamento *client side* usando hash](http://sammyjs.org/) (sugerido pelo @mgibsonbr)
- [Pergunta relacionada no Stack-EN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015613/3153542)

Comment: Muito obrigado @Andrey, estava lendo sua resposta e acho que o History API pode ser o mais útil.

Comment: Eu quero exatamente isso http://html5demos.com/history

Comment: Caso se decida usar a solução dos hashes, uma biblioteca como a [SammyJS](http://sammyjs.org/) pode ajudar a não ter que fazer tudo na mão. E é bom frisar que ainda que o History API funcione, é preciso garantir que o servidor dê suporte às URLs "artificiais" criadas por ele (o próprio demo linkado acima diz: "Nota: como essas urls não são reais, recarregar a página vai cair em uma url inválida."). Pois se o usuário salvar o endereço da página nos favoritos, por exemplo, ao voltar nele ele espera encontrar a página certa - na seção certa - e isso é algo que você vai ter que dar suporte.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Não conhecia o Sammy.js, até incluí na resposta. E de fato há várias considerações que devem ser feitas antes de tomar a decisão de usar roteamento *client side*.