# Fazer click automático ao abrir site

Tags: jquery, html

Ontem eu fiz [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32827/como-criar-uma-url-amig%C3%A1vel-em-uma-one-page/32866#32866), e ocorreu tudo certo. 
O que eu preciso, é que quando eu abra o site diretamente no link www.meusite.com.br/teste ele abra exatamente onde está o "teste", eu utilizei scrollTop para navegação.

Então, creio que o ideal, é ser feito em JS um clique automático direto no meu menu.
Segue abaixo meu HTML:

```
<ul class='menuItensPrincipal'>
    <li class='menuFixoListHome'>
        <div id='home' class='menuFixoListNome'><a href="home">Home</a></div>
        <div class='menuFixoListFechar'></div>
    </li>
    <li class='clear'></li>
    <li class='sobrehotel menuFixoList'><a href="/sobre-o-hotel">Sobre o Hotel</a></li>
    <li class='tarifario menuFixoList'><a href="/tarifarios">Tarif&aacute;rio</a></li>
    <li class='noticias menuFixoList'><a href="/noticias">Not&iacute;cias</a></li>
    <li class='reservas menuFixoList'><a href="/reservas">Reservas</a></li>
    <li class='contato menuFixoList'><a href="/contato">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

O Jquery:

```
$('#reserva').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHistory("Reserva", "/reserva");
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '4680px'
    }, 700);
});
$('#localizacao').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHistory("Localização e Contato", "/contato");
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '5677px'
    }, 700);
});
$('.sobrehotel, #sobrehotelRodape, #acomodacoes, #estrutura').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHistory("Sobre o Hotel", "/sobre-o-hotel");
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '1000px'
    }, 700);
});
$('.tarifario, #tarifarioRodape').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHistory("Tarifário", "/tarifario");
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '2020px'
    }, 700);
});
$('.noticias, #noticiasRodape, .socialBalao').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHistory("Notícias", "/noticias");
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '3000px'
    }, 700);
});
$('.reservas, #reservasRodape, #btReservaIr, #btReservaIr2').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHistory("Reserva", "/reserva");
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '4670px'
    }, 700);
});
$('.contato, #contatoRodape').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHistory("Contato", "/contato");
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '5678px'
    }, 700);
});
$('#home').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHistory("Home", "/home");
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '0'
    }, 700);
});
```

Então, se eu abrir colar no navegador o link http://www.meusite.com.br/teste ele clique direto no `li` e vá para o **scrollTop** que defini.

Tem como?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar um seletor jQuery para definir qual a li você quer clicar e apenas simular o click nela, para levar o usuário até o ponto.

```
$("li.classeDaLi").click();
```

Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tarifario, #tarifarioRodape').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setHistory("Tarifário", "/tarifario");
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: '2020px'
        }, 700);
        $("body").attr("link",".tarifario");
    });

    $('.sobrehotel, #sobrehotelRodape, #acomodacoes, #estrutura').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setHistory("Sobre o Hotel", "/sobre-o-hotel");
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: '1000px'
        }, 700);

        $("body").attr("link",".sobrehotel"); 
    });


    var link = $("body").attr("link");
    $(link).click();
});
```

Repare que agora está dinâmico. Você só precisa de um click. Quando você clica em um link ele adiciona um atributo no body que indica a página que você está. E quando você usa o click apos todos, ao abrir qualquer uma ele já vai pro lugar correto.

Esse treco: $("body").attr("link",".tarifario"); você terá que incluir em todos com a classe específica.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joayryx9/5/, fiz aqui. Só que nesse caso, a unica forma que tem pra isso dar certo é que as classes sejam iguais ao link. exemplo: /sobre-o-hotel, a classe da li tem que ser sobre-o-hotel

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17268/discussion-between-joao-paulo-and-felipe-stoker).

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // ao término do carregamento do arquivo
  $('#ELEMENTO QUE VOCÊ QUER').click(); // disparar o click de determinado elemento
  $(this).scrollTop(); // scroll para o topo, pode ser necessário adequar o seletor, ou seja, em vez de $(this), $(window)... ou outro...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a variável `window.location.pathname` para obter o PATH da URI e o seletor `A[href=...]` para disparar o click no link correto.

```
$('.menuFixoList A[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').click();
```

Outro detalhe que não pude deixar de perceber, você complicou demais a sua vida criando uma função para cada link e ainda definindo manualmente o scroll em PX de cada um, sugiro que você pegue o próprio `offset().top` de cada elemento, assim:

```
$('.menuFixoList A').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var classe = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    setHistory($(this).text(), $(this).attr('href'));
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('div.'+classe+'.conteudo').offset().top
    }, 700);
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/Ljja0vdh/).